# Button Horizontally inline with text boxes Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I Have the following form on a view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddInterest", "Club", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="well bs-component">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                            <h3>Not listed? - Add extras here</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClubTypeId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClubId)
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row col-md-offset-1 col-md-11">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InterestName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InterestName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InterestName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new {  htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>  model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn- success" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Everything is good apart from the submit button sits inline horizontally with the labels not the editor boxes, how can I get it to drop down?

i.e.

Label               Label

Text Box            Text Box        Button

NOT

Label               Label           Button

Text Box            Text Box

Its currently showing like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you just `pull-right` on the input?  `class="btn btn-success pull-right"`

Comment: if you want the button in its own row, then you will have to take it out of the current row and create a new row below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should recreate your form following this pattern:

```
 <div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InterestName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
     <div class="col-md-8">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InterestName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InterestName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>                          
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
       <div class="col-md-8">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new {  htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>  model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
           <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" />
       </div>
  </div>
```

More information at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

**Edit**

If you want them inline vertically:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InterestName)
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InterestName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new {  htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

More information at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

**Edit 2**

If you want them inline horizontally but in two columns and submit button aligned to the right:

```
<form>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InterestName)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InterestName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new {  htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top: 25px;">Add</button>
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry when i say inline I mean inline horizontally, that code does it vertically

Comment: That puts everything in a row including the labels and the submit button under the description box not inline. Ive edited the original post to show where the button was originally

Comment: In that case you should put a `style="margin-top: 25px;"` in the input button because it has no `<label>` above. Check my edited answer again

Comment: Brilliant thanks @Fabio Luz thats spot. Thanks for your patience and the link is a great resource too